# Use django admin to save to different data tables based on user roles

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am using django to build a cms system and want to implement the audit function by uploading ordinary users content to transit table.

Overwriting `save model` does not work because there are some inline tables.

And I have a doubt, when the `admin class` is registered with model, can it save the data(obj) to other model?

Comment: You need to show your save_model method

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is always a good idea to add some code, so that the community knows what your already have worked on and can help you better.